# Trying to make <textarea> mimic a <div>

Tags: html, css

curently I have this for HTML and CSS respectively:.....How would I contruct CSS and html that looks the same using a `<div>`. The one I created had horizontal scrolling and looked crazy.

```
<textarea class="textarea_readonly" readonly="readonly" name="mcRemarkOld" rows="7" cols="100" scrolling="auto"></textarea>
```

---

```
.textarea_readonly
{
    background-color: #DDDDD0;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What do you need this for? Why not use a textarea? What do you mean by "mimic" exactly seeing as it's a read-only one?

Comment: because I need to put a <a href> in that area...another post i made explained I couldnt do that...so I used a <div>. It worked but the div looked really funky..mimc just means looks styled the same with dimensions...clarification

Comment: div.tarea {

background-color: #DDDDD0;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    
    font: small courier, monospace black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px; 
    overflow: auto; 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to mimic a div, replace the textarea using JavaScript. Usage (run on load):

```
var textarea = document.getElementsByName("mcRemarkOld")[0];
turnTextAreaIntoDiv(textarea);

function turnTextAreaIntoDiv(elem){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    // Copy significant attributes, customize.
    div.className = elem.className;
    div.style.cssText = elem.style.cssText;
    div.id = elem.id;
    div.name = elem.name;
    div.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML; //`<a>` turns in  &lt;a&gt;
    elem.parentNode.replaceChild(div, elem);
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7bTNH/**

Comment: question....am I calling this function onload?...because I notice you have variable set before the function call?...or am I looking at the wrong

Comment: `[0]` had to be added, because `getElementsByTagName` returns a Node array. See this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7bTNH/